# data.addRows not working in google chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to draw a line chart using google API.

But the chart is not drawn and I could identify some error in data.addRows(rows); because the alert after this data.addRows line does not pop-up.

The alert popsup if I give it before data.addRows(rows).

I have no idea what went wrong here. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      function drawLineChart() {
          var date = 0;
          var status = 0;
          var rows = new Array();
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          var $attendance_date =  new Array();
          var $attendance_status = new Array();

          $attendance_date[0] = '2004';
          $attendance_date[1] = '2005';
          $attendance_date[2] = '2006';

          $attendance_status[0] = 1;
          $attendance_status[1] = 3;
          $attendance_status[2] = 5;

          rows.push(['Year', 'Sales']); 
          for(var i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
            date = $attendance_date[i];
            status = parseInt($attendance_status[i]);
            rows.push([date, status]);
          }

          data.addColumn('string', 'Subject');
          //  alert(rows);
          data.addRows(rows);
          alert(rows);

          var options = {
          title: 'My Chart',
          'width':900,
           'height':320, 
           'backgroundColor': '#d9d9e4'
          };

          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_attendance_div'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

There are a whole load of problems with what you're doing, let's go through them one by one.

First off, when using `addRow` and `addColumn`, you define headers with the `addColumn` command. So you can remove the following line:

```
rows.push(['Year', 'Sales']);
```

Secondly, you are defining a single column as 'Subject', when you really have two columns ('Year' and 'Sales'). You should define both columns:

```
data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
```

Once you do this, you can use the addRows command with the final (working) code:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  var date = 0;
  var status = 0;
  var rows = new Array();
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  var $attendance_date =  new Array();
  var $attendance_status = new Array();

  $attendance_date[0] = '2004';
  $attendance_date[1] = '2005';
  $attendance_date[2] = '2006';

  $attendance_status[0] = 1;
  $attendance_status[1] = 3;
  $attendance_status[2] = 5;

  // This line is commented out because it should be deleted
  // rows.push(['Year', 'Sales']);
  for(var i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
    date = $attendance_date[i];
    status = parseInt($attendance_status[i]);
    rows.push([date, status]);
  }
  // This line is commented out because it should be deleted
  // data.addColumn('string', 'Subject');

  // These lines should be added for column headers
  data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');

  //  alert(rows); 
  data.addRows(rows);
  // alert(rows);

  var options = {
    title: 'My Chart',
    'width':900,
    'height':320,
    'backgroundColor': '#d9d9e4'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

But if you're going to go this far, you may as well go the next step. Right now you are creating a new array, populating it in a for loop, and passing the array to the `addRows` command. Why not cut out the middle man?

```
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      var $attendance_date =  new Array();
      var $attendance_status = new Array();

      $attendance_date[0] = '2004';
      $attendance_date[1] = '2005';
      $attendance_date[2] = '2006';

      $attendance_status[0] = 1;
      $attendance_status[1] = 3;
      $attendance_status[2] = 5;

      data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');

      for(var i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
        data.addRow([$attendance_date[i], parseInt($attendance_status[i])])
      }
```

Presto, your code is much simpler and you are skipping a step.